# Laravel Controller for CRUD without querying Database inside Controller's methods

Tags: php, laravel, command-line-interface, laravel-artisan

It's possible to pass the right model object inside CRUD methods without query the database inside the method itself?

If you look at the DOC, You can see that controller's methods accepts the ID from the URL as a param.

```
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers
```

But, if You generate a Controller using artisan CLI, so the methods accept not the IDs as param but Request objects and or Model object, for example Post $post.
So, how can I be sure that Laravel correctly query the DB for me and pass the Model as a param? If I try this, the view is correctly rendered but the data are not passed in response.

### Example method from the DOCS

```
 /**
 * Show the profile for the given user.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    return view('user.profile', ['user' => User::findOrFail($id)]);
}
```

### Example method from the CLI generated Controller

```
    /**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Order  $order
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show(Order $order)
{
    //
}
```

Notice the difference in parameters.

### Runned Artisan Command

php artisan make:model Order -mcr
Ref: https://quickadminpanel.com/blog/list-of-16-artisan-make-commands-with-parameters/

## Solution

You have t look at https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding, Explicit Binding and define the model in the Router in the AppServiceProvider's boot as follows:

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Route::model('ordini', \App\Order::class);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Mattia - ive tried reading your question, but simply cant figure out what is heads and tails in your question. Id love to help if I can, but can you maybe re-write the question so there is a more organised approch, and maybe also post some of the code in question.

Comment: Hi @Patrick, look at my edit, and please let me know if You need more editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking route model binding
https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#route-model-binding

If you have a route like `user/{user}` you can resolve user model with type hinting

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Store a new user.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(\App\User $user)
    {
        $name = $user->name;

        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, if i try this `    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  \App\Order  $order
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show(\App\Order $order)
    {
        return view("orders.show")->with("order", $order);
    }` i get `[]` in the view (an empty array). The routes are standard, generated by Route::resources() method.

Comment: I've tested Route Model Binding, it works bu only if i mannually define Routes with Route::get(). If I use Route::resources() not working. It's normal?

Comment: Hello) It should working with Route::resources('orders') too

Comment: Hello, look at the end of the question for the solution.

Comment: That's why I ask to show route:list. With parameter order `orders/{order}`, you don't need an explicit model binding

Comment: i don't know. In my case it workeds only if I define the model into the boot. But I consoder It solved. Thanks for your help.